# jQuery DataTables CSV export utf-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to export my datatable to CSV. How to specify utf-8 encoding?

http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/3058/

*Mamadou Diôf* become *Mamadou DiÃ´f* after the export

I've tryied to add `"bom":true` but still the problem

Comment: "Mamadou Diôf","Junior Technical Author","San Francisco","1562","2009/01/12","$86,000" . this what i got in csv

Comment: how do you open your file? with excel or another text editor? did you tried to pass the option `charset: 'utf-8'` to the options of any of your defined buttons?

Comment: I'm opening the file with Excel 2003. No I haven't tryied yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put bom in csv extend option:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var dataSet = [
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
[ "Mamadou Diôf", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ]
];

$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary" }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
           extend: 'csv',
           charset: 'UTF-8',
           fieldSeparator: ';',
           bom: true,
           filename: 'CsvTest',
           title: 'CsvTest'
        }
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to support Bengali like this 'মো. খায়রুল বাসার' while exporting to PDF in jQuery Datatable?  I have added 'charset' but its showing some boxes in the PDF documents. If you could help then it would be great.